# Make screenshot of running process using pyscreenshot

Tags: python-3.x, process, screenshot

I want to make a screenshot of a running process so i could save the image afterwards, though without the window / process being in view of the screen itself?

IF it's possible, i'd like to know.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

It depends what is the process UI toolkit, for example, in *kivy* you can call `export_to_png("test.png")` on the root *Widget*. other UI toolkits offer different API to do so.